# How can I edit a Word Document using the windows-rs rust crate?

Tags: windows, rust, com, windows-runtime

I developed some code using the python pywin32 package to insert citations into Microsoft Word, and while it does work, I'd like to convert this code into a much more compact and efficient rust executable. I see that the windows-rs crate appears to be similar to the pywin32 python package, but I don't see many similarities when it comes to interacting with Microsoft office files and documents. Is there any documentation I am missing? If not, could anyone with expertise in the field point me to the most appropriate functions so I could play with it? My python code is located at the following github link if you are interested in perusing it: https://github.com/ryandikdan/InCite and an example of inserting a citation is shown in this code snippet

```py
import win32com.client as win32

def add_citation(xml_string):
    # Select Microsoft Word
    word = win32.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")
    # Select the active document (not sure if this will work if multiple files are open, but one is in front? could specify a specific file in the future with:
    # doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(r"C:\\temp\\testing.docx")
    doc = word.ActiveDocument
    # Adds the formatted xml from the other functions to the document, which should also add it to the master list I think.
    doc.Bibliography.Sources.Add(xml_string)
```

I haven't been able to find any appropriate functions in the documentation:
https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/index.html

Also the page on doc.rs seems to have less options:
https://docs.rs/windows/latest/windows/index.html

Comment: Well, you have [`GetActiveObject`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Ole/fn.GetActiveObject.html), but it requires a GUID instead of a string. I think that for that you use [`CLSIDFromString`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Com/fn.CLSIDFromString.html). Then I think you can call the member functions with the good, old [`IDispatch::Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-invoke).

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm very much a novice when it comes to CLSID and IDispatch (I don't know what they mean or do and I can't really find succinct information about them). I particularly can't find information with how they relate to Microsoft Office or Word. Is there a specific CLSID for Word? Or is there a website that lists the appropriate information for calling them?

Answer (score 4):

`CLSID` is just Class ID, to identify a COM class. `IDispatch` is an interface that provides a way to invoke methods on a COM object. It is a standard interface that is implemented by most COM objects, including those provided by Microsoft Office.

Here's an implementation on how you can use `IDispatch` interface to invoke methods on the Word objects, such as the Bibliography object:

```rust
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use winapi::{
    shared::{
        ntdef::NULL,
        windef::HWND,
        variant::{SafeArrayAccessData, SafeArrayCreateVector, SafeArrayUnaccessData, VARIANT},
    },
    um::{
        oaidl::{IDispatch, VARIANT_get_disp},
        oleauto::{CLSID_WordApplication, GetActiveObject, SysStringLen, SysStringPtr},
        winuser::{FindWindowA, HWND_BROADCAST, SendMessageA, WM_COMMAND},
    },
};
use windows::Interface;

const xml_string: &str = r#"<Source Tag="Crablang2023" SourceType="Book">
    <Author>
        <Last>Lang</Last>
        <First>Crab</First>
    </Author>
    <Title>CrabLang: The Definitive Guide</Title>
    <Publisher>Independently Published</Publisher>
    <Year>2023</Year>
</Source>"#;

const hwnd: HWND = unsafe { FindWindowA("OpusApp".as_ptr() as _, null_mut()) };

const word: IDispatch = unsafe {
    let mut word_disp: *mut IDispatch = null_mut();
    let hr = GetActiveObject(&CLSID_WordApplication, null_mut(), &mut word_disp);
    if hr < 0 {
        panic!("Failed to get IDispatch interface for Word app");
    }
    IDispatch::from_raw(word_disp)
};

const bibliography: IDispatch = unsafe {
    let result: VARIANT = word.invoke("Bibliography", &[]).unwrap();
    let mut bibliography_disp: *mut IDispatch = null_mut();
    let hr = VariantGetDispatch(&result, &mut bibliography_disp);
    if hr < 0 {
        panic!("Failed to get IDispatch interface for Bibliography object");
    }
    IDispatch::from_raw(bibliography_disp)
};

const xml_var: VARIANT = VARIANT {
    vt: VT_BSTR,
    bstrVal: unsafe { SysAllocString(xml_string.as_ptr() as _) },
    ..VARIANT::default()
};

const _result: Result<VARIANT, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> = bibliography.invoke("Sources.Add", &[&xml_var.into()]).unwrap();

fn update_bibliography(hwnd: HWND, xml_var: VARIANT) {
    unsafe {
        SysFreeString(xml_var.bstrVal); // free allocated memory
        SendMessageA(
            hwnd,
            WM_COMMAND,
            0x0000_07D0, // ID of the "Update Citations and Bibliography" command
            HWND_BROADCAST,
        )
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. This is definitely what I'm looking for, but many of the imported dependencies don't seem to work with the most recent versions of winapi or windows crates. Can you tell me the versions I'd need to use? It throws 7 errors: ```unresolved imports `winapi::shared::ntdef`, `winapi::shared::windef`, `winapi::shared::variant`, `winapi::um::oaidl`, `winapi::um::oleauto`, `winapi::um::winuser````